# How to group values in Calculated Field in DevExpress XtraReport Detail Band?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, devexpress, xtrareport

I am attempting to move a report over from Crystal Reports to Repx and designing the report in DevExpress XtraReports.

The existing Crystal Reports code is as follows:

```
if {Balance} = 0 then 0 
else if IsNull({Series}) Then ({Balance} / Sum ({Balance}, {ID})*100) -- Grouped by ID on this line
else ({Balance} / Sum ({Balance}, {Series})*100) -- Grouped by Series on this line
```

I have tried to mimic this code and move it in XtraReports and have as follows..

```
Iif([Balance] = 0, '0', 

Iif(IsNull([Series]), (([Balance] / Sum([Balance])) * 100), 

([Balance] / Sum([Balance])) * 100)) -- As you can see on this and the above line I am missing the group 
                                     -- by "ID" and "Series" I don't believe the syntax exists in XtraReports.
```

This is being complete in a detail band, so can't use the usual methods off adding a group header/footer etc.

Is it possible to group like the Crystal Report example in XtraReports?

Answer (score 0):

The [Parent Relationship Traversal Operator ('^')](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/120104/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/use-expressions/expression-constants-operators-and-functions#specify-parent-relations) allows you to compare a group value from a processed group with a value of a currently processed record within an expression. If a report is grouped by `ID` column, and you'd like to summarize the `Balance` column value for a currently processed group in a detail band, use the following expression (replacement for the `Sum ({Balance}, {ID})` function):

`[][[ID] = [^.ID]].Sum([Balance])`